# What is $\operatorname{max}(x)$ given that $ x \equiv n^p \pmod{q}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, equivalence-relations

Look at this:

$$ x \equiv n^p \pmod{q} $$

What is $\operatorname{max}(x)$?

Comment: Any assumptions on $p, q$?

Comment: They are prime and they are quite large.

Comment: Or how do I go about finding it? I'm just trying to find the upper limit for a gadget used in a C++ program.

Comment: Would it just be $q$? Oh, $_g$od if that's the case, then I might need to redesign this program.

Comment: $n$ is quite tiny.

Answer (score 1):

It's somewhat meaningless to ask what is $\max(x)$ since if $n^p\equiv x\pmod{q}$, then $n^p\equiv (x+kq)\pmod{q}$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, so there's no upper limit.

Assuming that you are limiting $x$ to be in the range $[0,q-1)$, then the answer depends on $n,p$.  If $n$ is what's called a [primitive root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n) modulo $q$, then the powers of $n$ hit every element in $(0,q-1)$ in turn.  It's possible that $n^p\equiv q-1$, your worst nightmare.  Even if $n$ is not a primitive root modulo $q$, that doesn't really help much, as its powers are more or less evenly scattered among $(0,q-1)$, so the largest it gets is only slightly smaller than $q$.

Answer (score -1):

If $q$ is a prime, then as $n$ ranges over $q$, this will define a finite field. Hence the maximum value it could be over $\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$ is $q-1$. However, this doesn't really help for a non-specific $n$.

Likely, if you are trying to calculate this in a program, the easiest way would be to directly calculate $n^{p} \ (mod \ q)$ utilizing exponentiation by squaring, and the fact that you only need to keep track of $q$ digits. This will give you a solution in $log \ p$ time. This may or may not be feasible depending on the exact size of $p$ and $q$.